# Adding DataFrames with partially overlapping indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have two Pandas DataFrames I'd like to add together, with a datetime index, and a set of common columns.

The datetime indices will have 95% common values, but some of the rows in `df2` may not be in `df1` and vice versa.

I'd like to add the two DataFrames together, and when one of the DataFrames do not have the index the other does just treat is as `0` (or take the one with a value, whichever is better).

The result should **not** drop any indices, i.e. something like an outer join, rather than an inner.

I have tried `pd.add`, but that appears to drop `NaN` results where both DataFrames do not have an entry.

`pd.concat` works where they don't have common indices, but where they do I get duplicates instead of adding together. Do I have to do a second `groupby` sum step? I thought there'd be a simpler way to do this.

For example:

**FRAME 1**

| Month | Val 1 | Val 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-02-01 | 3 | 4 |
| 2022-03-01 | 5 | 6 |

**FRAME 2**

| Month | Val 1 | Val 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 | 101 | 102 |
| 2022-04-01 | 103 | 104 |
| 2024-01-01 | 105 | 106 |
| 2025-01-01 | 107 | 108 |

**DESIRED RESULT**

| Month | Val 1 | Val 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-02-01 | 3 | 4 |
| 2022-03-01 | 106 | 108 |
| 2022-04-01 | 103 | 104 |
| 2024-01-01 | 105 | 106 |
| 2025-01-01 | 107 | 108 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this works for you :)

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby(["Month"]).sum().reset_index()
```

Output

```
    Month   Val1    Val2
0   2022-01-01  1   2
1   2022-02-01  3   4
2   2022-03-01  106 108
3   2022-04-01  103 104
4   2024-01-01  105 106
5   2025-01-01  107 108
```

Comment: if you use `as_index` parameter in `groupby`, you can save on the `reset_index` I think. Upvoted, this is very intuitive.

Comment: Yep, this works. Thanks! Whenever I need to do multiple steps joining data in Pandas I feel like I'm doing something wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "Month"s are indexes (if not `set_index('Month')` first), we could use `reindex` each DataFrame with the union of the indexes, `fillna` and `add`:

```
idx = df1.index.union(df2.index)
out = df1.reindex(idx).fillna(0).add(df2.reindex(idx).fillna(0)).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
            Val 1  Val 2
Month                   
2022-01-01      1      2
2022-02-01      3      4
2022-03-01    106    108
2022-04-01    103    104
2024-01-01    105    106
2025-01-01    107    108
```